# Add Class To Element If it already has a specific class

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to dynamically add a class to `slide-content` and `slide-buttons` within the `Bootstrap Carousel`'s caption div. I want my code to add the class `animate` only when the the parent div with the class `item` has the class `active` added to it. (the class`active` is added only when the item slides in in.). Here is the basic HTML of the Carousel.

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="slide-content>
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="slider-buttons">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Item 1 -->
    <!-- Item 2 -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="slide-content>
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="slider-buttons">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Item 2 -->
    ...
  </div>
```

And, here is what I tried.

```
$item = $('.carousel-inner > .item');
$( $('.carousel-inner > .item') ).each(function() {
if ( this.hasClass('active') ) {
    $('.carousel-caption > .slide-content, .carousel-caption > .slider-buttons').addClass('animated');
} else {
    $('.carousel-caption > .slide-content, .carousel-caption > .slider-buttons').removeClass('animated');
}
});
```

Now, when I remove the jQuery's `each` function, it adds the class `animated` to all the elements when any of the item gets the class `active`. Also, it doesn't remove the class at all (since the the class`active` is there, inspite of the parent div.). And, when I add the `each` function, it doesn't work at all.

Please help.

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle? When you are using `addClass` (or `removeClass`) you are targeting all the elements that you put in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the elements using proper selector

```
var inner = $('.carousel-inner');

//traverse not active item then find the buttons and remove the animated class
inner.find('> .item:not(.active) .carousel-caption').children('.slide-content .slider-buttons').removeClass('animated');

//traverse active item then find the buttons and add the animated class
inner.find('> .item.active .carousel-caption').children('.slide-content .slider-buttons').addClass('animated');
```

Comment: This one is great indeed because reverting back the previously animated makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

My guess :

```
  $('.carousel-inner :not(.active)').find('.slide-content,.slider-buttons').removeClass('animated');
  $('.carousel-inner .active').find('.slide-content,.slider-buttons').addClass('animated');
```

Btw, you forgot the closing double-quote in :

```
<div class="slide-content>
```

It should read this instead :

```
<div class="slide-content">
```

Comment: Thanks,
But it doesn't remove the class when the `active` class is not present in the parent `.item`.

Comment: Should be better, added a selector for not active, and then remove the class